# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')

Tags: redux, preact, vitest

I'm using vitest testing my code which is build with preact and redux. It works find when running the site but it failed in the testing.

To mock the redux store, I create a util function to render the component with redux Provider

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/preact";
import type { RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/preact";

type RenderWithReduxOptions = {
  initialState?: any;
  store?: AppStore;
};

function renderWithRedux(
  ui: JSX.Element,
  storeData?: RenderWithReduxOptions,
  options?: RenderOptions,
  renderFn = render,
) {
  const initialState = (storeData && storeData.initialState) || {};
  const store = (storeData && storeData.store);
  return renderFn(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>, options);
}
```

And in the test file, I use this function to render the component to be test:

```
import configureStore, { MockStoreEnhanced } from "redux-mock-store";

const mockStore = configureStore();

describe("Test something...", () => {
  let store: MockStoreEnhanced<unknown, {}>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      ...
    });
  });

  test("test ...", () => {
    renderWithRedux(
      <TestComponent />,
      { store },
    );
    ...
  });
});
```

Then run it with vitest and I got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4k49.png)

Seems the issue is happened in the redux component `Provider` because it works successfully when I take off the Provider. Not sure what the root cause is.

Comment: That usually means you're consuming multiple instances of Preact at once. React and Preact both with hooks rely upon being loaded as a singleton -- having two copies at once breaks the hooks API.